# Django can not sent email with attachments

Tags: django, python-2.7, email

I am trying to sent email by using this code. But when I was trying. Either html or email attachment in sent. **But not both**. If I omit attachment email body is sent. **but if I add attachment email body is not sent** . Please someone provide you suggestion.

```
  msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=self.mail_subject, from_email=from_mail, to=(to,),
                                         connection=connection)
            if isinstance(attachment, list):
                for attach_path in attachment:
                    msg.attach_file(attach_path)

            msg.attach_alternative(html_with_context_data, "text/html")
            try:
                msg.send(fail_silently=True)
            except:
                pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With code like this what do you expect?

```
        try:
            msg.send(fail_silently=True)
        except:
            pass
```

You are telling django to fail **silently** which means it will not tell you if something goes wrong. And even if you switched off the silent mode, your exception handling is going to make sure that you never ever hear about it!!

Never do this

```
        except:
            pass
```

Always catch specific extensions, and on the rare cases that you need to catch generic exceptions like this, log it.

```
import traceback

except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Then you will see why exactly your attachment is not being sent.

(perhaps this should be a comment but it's far too long for that)

Comment: Ya. I am working what you have said. but still it is not working. No exception. Email is passing but not with both attachment and HTML.

Comment: obvious next step is to check the mail log.

Comment: I am using gmail. How can I get log?

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 hours I have added only one line. Now I am getting both HTML and attachment.

```
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
```